# Symfony form - Entity type plus join table

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

### Question

How do you use an entity form type to display using one type of entity, but process as another entity?

### Info

I have 3 entities: `Job(id, name, ..)`, `JobSkill(job_id, skill_id, ..)` and `Skill(id, name)`
[`Job` -OneToMany- `JobSkill`, `JobSkill` -ManyToOne- `Skill`]
*JobSkill is essentially a join table with extra columns.*

The form is setup with a field for *skills*, this should be displayed as multiple checkboxes - using (Fig 1.0) I get the desired display.

However `Job` entity is connected to `JobSkill`, not `Skill`, so now I have to tell the `Job` entities add and remove skill methods to expect `Skill`, when it should expect `JobSkill` (Fig 1.1).

Ideally the add and remove will work directly with JobSkill (Fig 1.2).

This causes the cascade remove to call removeSkill() passing `Skill`, to remove a `JobSkill` via a `Skill` is a lot of effort.

N.B. The skills already exist in the DB, I am trying to let users select per job the ones they want to include.

Fig 1.0

```
    ...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
           ->add('skills', 'entity', [
               'label' => false,
               'attr' => [
                   'class' => 'skill-picker'
              ],
               'class' => 'Model\Entity\Skill',
               'property' => 'name',
               'expanded' => true,
               'multiple' => true,
               'by_reference' => false
           ]);

    }
    ...
```

Fig 1.1

```
    public function addSkill(\Model\Entity\Skill $skill)
    {
        $job_skill = new JobSkill();
        $job_skill->setJob($this);
        $job_skill->setSkill($skill);

        $this->skills[] = $job_skill;

        return $this;
    }
```

Fig 1.2

```
    public function addSkill(\Model\Entity\JobSkill $skill)
    {
        $this->skills[] = $skill;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Or perhaps there is a better setup of the form to produce the result?